# Using Platform.runLater to disable collapsing an Accordion in JavaFX

Tags: java, accordion, javafx-2

I want to use the solution suggested in the answer at:
[Prevent an accordion in JavaFX from collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403838/prevent-an-accordion-in-javafx-from-collapsing)
in order to prevent the Accordion in JavaFX from entirely collapsing.

My question is: why does the listener added on the expandedPaneProperty use Platform.runLater to call setCollapsible(false)?

Indeed, if I remove Platform.runLater, after collapsing/expanding the panes, their content disappears for some reason. So why does the runLater solve that problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea
Could you help answering this?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) of ChangeListener< T>  states, that:

**In general is is considered bad practice to modify the observed value in this method.**

Where this method refers to:

```
void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue);
```

---

**RunLater** ensures, that the Pane will be modiffied on the **next** run of the JavaFX Application Thread and so making modifications when it is safe to do them.

Comment: What you're saying would apply here if inside the ChangeListener we were modifying the value of the expandedPaneProperty, which is not the case. Here, we are just setting the collapsibleProperty for the same value of the expandedPaneProperty

Comment: While changing any of the properties of expandedPane - you are invalidating it.

Comment: That's not true. I think you are confusing 'changing the value' with 'modifying the same value instance'. If you change a property of expandedPane you are not changing its 'value', and hence Change/InvalidationListeners added to to expandedPane will not be notified.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean, but I don't agree about what "the sentence mentioned in the javadoc applies". Why would that be a bad practice? Your reasoning "Something that would make out of memory error wouldn't be named a bad practice" is correct, except that changing "the expandedPaneProperty inside its own changeListener"  does not have to necessarily cause an infinite loop. You can have checks e.g. something like only if(newValue==null) do a change. However, the javadoc is probably warning about it because you may cause an infinite loop if you're not careful with your checks.

Comment: @user1859872 I think, it's true what you said about the properties of the observed value. I filed a bug on this issue on javafx-jira [#RT-28140](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28140) Nevertheless i think that when something is called a "bad practice" by the javadoc, there is something more going on. I also filed a feature request for the accordion to be not collapsible [#RT-28141](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28141)